# How can i get the MacOS green + button function in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, macosx, maximized

Is there a way to get que MacOS zoom button (the one called "+" in green color) fuction in Ubuntu windows?

not to maximize windows, just to "optimize" them like in MacOS?

Here a video showing it function

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJobDUgITvI

It is supossed to change a windows size to the optimum

Comment: can you give a screenshot of it, many people dont use mac here and so wont know what it is or what it does

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? If so please post answer? I'm looking for a way to emulate the macosx zoom functionality too

Answer (score 0):

The application would have to hint as to what the optimum size is. This is a historic difference between X-Windows and MacOS. Applications under X will probably expect to be maximized, minimized and manually resized, but few will expect to choose an optimum size and there isn't a standard mechanism for telling them to do so.